# It's possible to check if an user has an active/valid session through REST API in Keycloak?

Tags: java, keycloak

It's possible to check if an user have an active/valid session through REST API?

I'm using the Java REST Admin client. I saw the UserSessionRepresentation returned by

```
List<UserSessionRepresentation> usr = Keycloak.realm("realmId").users().get("userId").getUserSessions();
```

But UserSessionRepresentation do not have the information I want.
It's possible?

Answer (score 5):

you can check your session with this address:

```
http://keycloakAddressAndPort/auth/realms/develop/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

if your session is not ok you see this response (http status code **401**):

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "User session not found or doesn't have client attached on it"
}
```

and if that is ok you see something like this (http status code **200**):

```
{
    "sub": "c0c25095-63e7-471d-a39e-f3b157c91fd7",
    "email_verified": true,
    "name": "Amir Azizkhani",
    "preferred_username": "a.azizkhani@...",
    "given_name": "Amir",
    "family_name": "Azizkhani",
    "email": "a.azizkhani@...."
}
```

complete postman json:

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "77ce65c3-948a-4b3d-a97b-b11cd00c593b",
        "name": "Spring Keycloak",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
    
        {
            "name": "openid-connect/userinfo",
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cC...",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "accept",
                        "value": "application/json"
                    }
                ],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://192.168.131.33:8080/auth/realms/develop/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "192",
                        "168",
                        "131",
                        "33"
                    ],
                    "port": "8080",
                    "path": [
                        "auth",
                        "realms",
                        "develop",
                        "protocol",
                        "openid-connect",
                        "userinfo"
                    ]
                },
                "description": "Dont forget to set Bearer value obtains from token request"
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific API endpoint that you've referenced here ([interface](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/integration/admin-client/src/main/java/org/keycloak/admin/client/resource/UserResource.java#LC267:%7E:text=List%3CUserSessionRepresentation%3E%20getUserSessions()%3B), [implementation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UserResource.java#LC335:%7E:text=public%20Stream%3CUserSessionRepresentation%3E%20getSessions())) *only* returns active/valid sessions for that user.  You could match on session id (or a variety of other things).  If a session is invalid, it is marked for removal and not returned for that endpoint.  So that seems like what you want.

But also realize that there are other sessions (like offline-sessions) if you're looking for that.  Check the linked source for more information or other endpoints if desired.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want [that one](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/rest-api/#_get_client_session_stats) to get the list of the active client sessions:

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/client-session-stats
```

Description

> The key is the client id, the (returned) value is the number of sessions that
>   currently are active with that client. Only clients that actually have
>   a session associated with them will be in this map.

Comment: The information in the link may answer the question, but it is better to put the essential details in your answer. This makes it easier for a reader to quickly understand the value of your answer, and means that your answer will continue to be useful even if the link becomes dead.

Comment: Thank you for your repply Borys Zibrov, but is not what I want. As described, the client stats returns information about sessions of clients used to access Keycloak, not user sessions.

Answer (score -1):

The endpoint to use is:

http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/{YourRealm}/users/{userID}/sessions

Replace userID with the user's ID and YourRealm with your Realm. A list of all the sessions of the user will be returned. If the user is not logged in an empty list will be returned.

Note: You have to enter Client Bearer token as Authentication with the call.